# Mean of each column of multiple dataframes to a dataframe - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df as follows:

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
2  1  2 
3  3  1
```

And I would like the mean of every column and make a dataframe with it.
That would be in this example:

```
A B C
2 2 2
```

The code I did was:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('ABC')) # To create df
dfs = np.array_split(df.sample(frac=1),4) # Split it in 4
daf = []
for i in range(len(dfs):
   daf.append(dfs[i].mean())
daf.to_frame()
```

However I am unable to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), but because it return `Series` use [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose:

```
df = df.mean().to_frame().T
print (df)
     A    B    C
0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([df.mean()])
print (df)
     A    B    C
0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

For multiple `DataFrames`:

```
daf = []
for i in dfs:
   daf.append(i.mean().to_frame().T)

print (daf[0])
         A         B        C
0 -0.92493  1.022305  1.52295
```

what is same as `list comprehension` solution:

```
daf = [i.mean().to_frame().T for i in dfs]
```

Comment: If  it is multiple dataframes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

the method of dataframe, 'apply' will be good. 
the code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('ABC')) # To create df
df.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x), axis=0)
```